# FastAPI recursive response model

Tags: recursion, fastapi, pydantic

I am using FastAPI and I have a recursive model as below:

```
class Category(BaseModel):
    title: str
    category_id: int
    category_path: str
    children: list[Category]
```

I am using `from __future__ import annotations` and it was working fine until I use it as a response model.

```
@router.get("/categories/{cat_id}")
async def get_categories(cat_id: Annotated[int, Path(description="The category id")]) -> Category:
    params = {"catid": cat_id}
    return client.get_categories(params)
```

The moment I include it as a response model, the endpoint still works when I use Postman but the documentation crashes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F700.png)

I tried changing my model according to this discussion and use ForwardRef and model_rebuild: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/7898

Comment: Since you haven't shown what `get_categories` are doing - could it be that you have a circular dependency here, effectively creating a category tree with infinite depth?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a SwaggerUI bug, FastAPI 0.104.1 includes a workaround. see https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/releases/tag/0.104.1